# Probability of 1st flip winning

Tags: probability

I was asked this question in an interview the other day

You keep flipping a coin and whilst you do this, you keep track of the number of heads and tails.

You can think of this as a race between heads and tails. For example if after 9 flips, you have 7 heads and 2 tails, then heads is winning the race by 5

Consider a race of 10 flips, What is the probability that the side you flip first will be winning the race?

My approach:
1st flip can be anything and out of the remaining 9 flips, we must get at least 5 more occurrences to win the race

$$\frac {1} {2^{9}} \left(\binom{9}{5} + \binom{9}{6} + \binom{9}{7} + \binom{9}{8}+1\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Is this approach correct?

Comment: A strange question for an interview.

Comment: Yes, the approach is correct.  A more elegant approach is that for $~k \in \{0,1,\cdots,4\},~$ since $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{k} = \binom{9}{9-k}~$ you must have (by symmetry) that the probability that at least $~5~$ of the $~9~$ coin tosses will be heads is the same as the probability that at least $~5~$ of the $~9~$ coin tosses will be tails.  Or, you could simply surmise the conclusion, since the *situation* involving flipping the coin $~9~$ times to get $~5~$ or more of one side versus the other is **symmetric** with respect to Heads and Tails.

Comment: Seems good to me! Alternatively you can look at it as a simple (1D) random walk going up or down with probability $1/2$ and steps being independent, and the question is equivalent to asking "what is the probability that if you first go up, you will still be in the upper half after 10 steps", which for nine steps is equivalent to going up strictly more often than going down and has probability one half.

Comment: You should clarify that the opposite of the first result must come at least $5$ times that the first result does NOT win , but apart from that a fine solution.